# gke cluster with preemtible node-pool

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I have 2 node-pools(pool1-regular,pool2-preemtible) in my cluster.
one node pool is preemtible and the other is regular.
beacuse i cant really trust preemtible machine i want  deploy my app so that at least one of my pods is in pool1-regular.
i managed to set the affinity so no pod with the same name will be scheduled to the same node.
but i dont now how to create some hybrid solution

Here's a link to my [deployment.yaml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3NfG_Q95Gj8R3Z1SFhKOVl6cG8/view?usp=sharing)

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The most direct solution is to create 2 deployments, one that uses the preemtible nodes and another that uses non preemtible. Both deoyments will have basically the same tags so you can have a single service exposing both.

Deployment A will include a `host=preemptible` and will use an affinity to schedule on preemtible nodes. Deployment B will do the same but with a non-preemptible label.